# Link to a specific route on a click of a button using react-routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've managed to assign different sections to different routes now I want to bee able to go to a specific rout by clicking a button element, I don't know how to do it.

```
import Home from './routes/Home';
import About from "./routes/About";
import ProductosSection from "./routes/ProductsSection";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/products" element={<ProductosSection />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here is the the file route that I want to display the content from

```
import React from "react";
import Products from "../products/products";

function ProductosSection() {
  return (
    <div className="ProductosSection">
      <Products />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductosSection
```

I have tried to link the routes from the file `Button.js`  where I have defined all my buttons but the `onClick` event does not respond the way I expected

```
export default function Buttoms() {
  return (  
    <button className="button">Home</button>
    <button className="button">About</button>
    <button className="button" onClick={() => ("/products")} >Products</button>
  )
}
```

What is the right procedure to have the content from the route displayed by clicking on each button?

Answer (score 1):

`() => ("/products")` as a callback function is almost meaningless, it's a function that returns a string and nothing more. You will need to use the `navigate` function to effect a navigation action to navigate to any specified path. The `navigate` function is accessible via the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Buttons() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button"
        onClick={() => navigate("/home")}
      >
        Home
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button"
        onClick={() => navigate("/about")}
      >
        About
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button"
        onClick={() => navigate("/products")}
      >
        Products
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```